# Inconsistent styling of [status-completed] in tag sets

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

There is an inconsistency in the display of [status-completed] in tag sets.

The *proper* styling, judging from looking at the status-* tags across all sites in a tag set seems to be a red background with white text.

---

Some display this correctly:
[image: completed correct on meta.math]

[image: completed correct on meta.english]

---

However, on some sites, the display is different and the shadow makes the text difficult to read.
[image: completed incorrect on meta.stackoverflow]

[image: completed incorrect on meta.webapps]

---

Note that other status-* tags display properly on the sites where status-completed does not:
[image: declined correct on meta.stackoverflow]

---

Also, side request, could the required tags get a bit more styling distinction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've visited the tag links that display weird, so the `.tags:visited` styles end up being applied as the selector is more specific than `.moderator-tag` (this is similar to the issue with moderator tag links here on Meta). The `.moderator-tag:visited` selector should probably just be added to the current moderator tag style block, as this is how the plain tags one is defined.

As for the required tags, I personally think changing the border colour to something like `#D0D0D0` would be alright:

[image]

Not sure if that's distinguishable enough for everyone though.

Comment: excellent fix, this was driving me mad

Comment: Oy, I feel silly for not noticing it was questions I'd visited. ):

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's repeatable across PCs in Chrome but non-deterministic for me .. some questions have it, others won't -- even between pge refreshes.

Weird CSS issue!